# can I REQUEST_SYNC to update devices?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

I need update devices, can I REQUEST_SYNC to do it?

[here](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs/issues/18) say this api is not public yet.
what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

You can get an API Key for the HomeGraph APIs. You make a call to their API endpoint with your API key:

`https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:requestSync?key=API_KEY`

In the body, make sure you provide the `agentUserId` that you originally returned in your **SYNC** response. This will cause your endpoint to receive another **SYNC** call.

Here's a cURL command:

```
curl -i -s -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{agent_user_id: \"agentUserId\"}" "https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:requestSync?key=API_KEY"
```

Check [the new docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app#request) to learn a bit more about how it is used.

Comment: Google seems to have enabled the Homegraph API in the developer console now... I can call it with an API key, but it seems to be undocumented, so I don't know what to call it with. I tried duplicating what was leaked in the node samples: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs

Comment: I am unaware that of any API visibility changing. I would not rely on the current APIs indefinitely as they may change or be unstable.

Comment: REQUEST_SYNC is an operation of Google's Homegraph API, which was just recently enabled in the Google Cloud Console. You can now add it to your project, and use your API key to call it, as demonstrated in the commits to that repo I linked (later removed, you have to look at history). We can hit the endpoint, but dont have docs on what to send it yet.

Comment: Hey there, we just added the docs on how to use the feature. We'll be updating the sample soon.

Comment: It's probably something wrong with the formatting of your payload. I've been testing it with the sample project and have gotten it to work consistently. Is it inside of your `payload` attribute?

Comment: Deleted my other comment Nick, but thank you, that was it, I had the agentUserId outside the payload object. Working, and can trigger updates with REQUEST_SYNC now, thank you!

Comment: No problem. Just make sure you accept this answer so others will be able to see how this is done.